# Spring web dependency for class loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I have a spring web project which I build using `maven-assembly-plugin` so that I can produce an uber/fat jar. I am also using spring web as I want to use `HttpRequest` & `HttpResponse`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**I want to run this Jar as a standalone app outside Tomcat** (In fact I am running another spring-boot app which is loading this app dynamically and then instantiating the class)

I then load this JAR using `ClassLoader` (Tried URLClassLoader as well as `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`) so that I can run a certain class.

But when I load all classes in the jar, I get an exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase`

To fix this I add `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient` dependency and run again to hit on:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.Callback`

Then I added `okhttp` and to hit on:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.synchronoss.cloud.nio.multipart.NioMultipartParserListener`

When I add `spring-boot-starter-web` then I get:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean`

I am not sure how far I should keep going this route. But my questions are:

1) Should the fat jat not pack all the dependencies needed to run in an isolated manner?

2) What is best way to run `spring-web` based app without tomcat like container

Update: Adding POM and other details:

```http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.company</groupId>
<artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>hello-world</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```

I am loading the JAR built with above descriptor in another place like this:

```
 jarFile = new JarFile(file);
        Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
        URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + file+"!/") };
        cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

        // Load all dependent classes from libraries etc. 
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
            if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
                continue;
            }
            String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
            className = className.replace('/', '.');
            //System.out.println("JE="+je.getName()+" &ClassName="+className);
            cl.loadClass(className);
```

The exception happens on last line - where it loads a class

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml and any descriptor files to the question?

Comment: @tgdavies Added details

Comment: What is your reason for loading every class in the jar? Is it to validate the jar, or for some other reason? Its possible that there are classes in your jar which will only be used in particular configurations, and your web app might run successfully. I would just try to start it and see.

Comment: @tgdavies I thought one had to load all dependent classes from JAR - as they might have been imported in the execution logic?

Comment: As long as the classloader that your springboot application is using is also looking at the jar you are creating here, classes will be loaded on demand. I think you need to explain more about what you are actually trying to achieve -- what your deployment looks like, and why this app is being dynamically loaded.

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies - I will add details soon once I have pushed on Github, since it is an open source project. I think in my case mistake was the container which was loading had those classes already and loading them from the JAR again caused some issue. Once i changed the spring-boot-starter-web to scope provided in the JAR being loaded, the exception disappeared.